# Value of type UIImage has no member dominantColors

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

So with a library that I have installed called 'KTSpectrum' I am calling an extension dominantColors on an image to return a UIColor object.

```
import KTSpectrum // this import the kMeans clustering library

@IBOutlet var tempImageView: UIImageView! // this hold a temporary image to be displayed in the view

let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

self.tempImageView.image = image
self.tempImageView.hidden = false

let colors = self.tempImageView.image!.dominantColors()
// this gives me the error Value of type UIImage has no member dominantColors
```

I have linked the framework and built it within the project. Still not sure what the error is telling me.

Comment: plz show us the link to KTSpectrum

Comment: what do you mean by link ? https://github.com/kylry/KTSpectrum

Comment: I have done everything I needed to according to the documentation. Other users with similar errors have said that the image needs to be unwrapped , etc , etc.

Comment: i ment what u posted ;-) don´t know KTSpecrum...

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the files directly into your Project:

- kMeans.swift
- Spectrum+UIImage.swift
- SpectrumDataTypes.swift
- SpectrumSettings.swift

and don't use CocoaPods. You don't have to use the "import KTSpectrum" row and everything will work fine, I just tried it myself.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just like to use CocoaPods to make everything look cleaner.